# Pledge payment off contact dashboard: "DB Error: No Such Field"

Tags: pledges

Drupal 7 / CiviCRM 4.7

When I create a Pledge and view it in my contact dashboard, I can see all of my pledge payments and their dates. If I select "Make Payment" it sends me to a page like: civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=31&pledgeId=3 and then errors out, "DB Error: No Such Field".

Is this implemented currently in CiviCRM, or is there a configuration missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug and is documented and fixed at [CRM-21465](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21465).  You will need to apply the [patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11305/files) to fix the problem or will need to wait for 4.7.30 release.